# Phonegap iFrame/page scaling

Tags: html, cordova, viewport

I have a page that uses the following code when dealing with mobile devices

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.7, maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=1">
```

This code works great when viewed in a web browser on a mobile device. Now I am trying to create a `Phonegap` application with this very same page in an iframe in the application. However, the scaling/viewport is not working at all. Regardless of the numbers I put in for the scaling, the scale is still the same. It will not change.

The reason I am trying to do this is that my `Phonegap` application is tying together two external pages on the same `Phonegap` page via two iframes and I need both pages to be able to be viewed at one time without running out side the screen.

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can use/enable scaling using iframes in `Phonegap`? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "that you have to go lower than normal on the viewport with Phonegap to achieve the same effect"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer. Someone posted it on the `Phonegap` `Google` group. Here's their response:

> Try setting the "EnableViewPortScale" setting to true: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_project-settings_ios_index.md.html#Project%20Settings%20for%20iOS

So I added the following to my config.xml file and it's now scaling like I want it to. Only caveat is that you have to go lower than normal on the viewport with `Phonegap` to achieve the same effect.

```
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
```