# How to open url inside the app with Keno Mobile similiar to UIWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app, kendo-mobile

I want to open a url that does not exit the app when it is deployed via Cordova / Phone Gap.

[UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Sample UIWebViewImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2mH1.png)

I want to do something similar retain the top NavBar of the app, but without the address bar.  When I currently visit a url it will open the whole screen into the app, without back/forward buttons or any of the navbar or tabbar navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [InAppBrowser of PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser).

Comment: Can you comment on why there is no other way like an iFrame or other solution? It has worked for me, but I wish I could still have the NavBar visible instead of a non styled browser open up.

Comment: Please see the answer from Troy in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212824/how-can-i-open-an-iframe-in-a-phonegap-cordova-app-running-on-ios . he was able to make it work using iframe... But again, InAppBrowser is the PhoneGap way to go..You can check this link too to achieve iframe solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862948/phonegap-iframe-page-scaling