# Pinch to Zoom Image in JQM/Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have looked through a number of different post here and cant seem to find a post that definitively solves this.  I am using JQM and Phonegap build and need a way to pinch to zoom an image.  I am clicking on the thumbnail of an image on one page and the image opens in a separate page.

How do I get pinch to zoom on the image on just this one page?

I found some post to hammerjs but never a complete solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what my image page looks like.

```
<div data-role="page" id="imagePage">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <a href="#home" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-corner-all" data-rel="back" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
    <h1>Image</h1>
</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div  id="imageContainer">
          <img src="myimage.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
<div data-role="page" id="imagePage" data-theme="d">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <a href="#home" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-nodisc-icon" data-rel="back" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
    <h1>Image</h1>
</div>
    <div data-role="content" id="imageContent" style="padding:0px;width:100%; height:100%;"> 
        <iframe id="myframe" src="ImageViewer.html" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
</div><!-- /Content -->
</div>
```

iframe page ImageViewer

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ImageViewer</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.panzoom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" style="width:100%;"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("img").panzoom();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function openImage(imageURL) {
var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument;
frameDoc.querySelector("img").src = imageURL;   
}
```

Updated the code above 12/2/14. Pinch zoom is working on the image.

Thanks

RGecy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the content in an iframe, and use gesture detection and css transforms to scale the content.

You will have to set the source of an `<img>` tag to the DOM, so your setup would look like this

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="imageViewer.html"></iframe>

<script>
var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument;
frameDoc.querySelector("img").src = "myimage.jpg"
</script>
```

and imageViewer.html you can use the jquery plugin [`jquery.panzoom`](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom) to do the scaling.

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.panzoom.js"></script>
</head><body><img />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").panzoom();
});
</script>
```

That should do it. Another option is to enable viewport scaling on a different html page, if that navigation doesn't disrupt the state of your your application since the page will be reloaded when you return. The meta tag setting that allows for scaling is this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=1">
```

and cordova has a preference in your config.xml

```
 <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
```

Its suggested in some other [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862948/phonegap-iframe-page-scaling), but I haven't tried it. Sadly, you [can't load the other page in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19112094/491506) since your page viewport settings prevent scaling.

Comment: I update my code above. I couldn't get the image to show in the iframe.  It seems the javascript breaks down at the x.contentDocument line.

Comment: Use frame.contentDocument instead...I updated the code snippet

Comment: Got the image to open in the iframe once I changed to frame.contentDocument, but pinch to zoom is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I had to move the meta tag inside the head section of the html document. The content property `user-scalable=1` is what enables zooming in the iframe. There may be an issue where the parent viewport overrides the child viewport.

Comment: You're going to have to use css transforms because the iframe's meta tag [wont be applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678454/allow-zooming-within-iframe-but-not-on-page-in-ios/19112094#19112094). I got it working with the jquery plugin `panzoom`, and updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much! Got it working. I also updated my code with the solution.  I am trying to get the drag or pan to work using one finger instead of two in Android.  It works fine iOS, but doesn't in Android on my S5. Any ideas?

Comment: One more issue I have come across.  Since I am injecting a new image into the iFrame page or even when I click on the same link for the image, the iframe does not reset the image to the original position.  Even new images are loaded and zoomed or panned to the position of the previous one.  How can I reset this each time an image loaded or my function is called?

Comment: If you inspect the DOM, you can see the css transform, that you need to reset.
<img src="img/logo.png" style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; cursor: move; transition: none; -webkit-transition: none; -webkit-transform: matrix(1.4348073892391513, 0, 0, 1.4348073892391513, 72.28865741400827, 10.229104345974633);">
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").panzoom();
      });
    </script>

</body>
To reset the transform with javascript, just clear the style property
`document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.querySelector('img').style.webkitTransform = ""`